# MySQL procedure with query string

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am a newbie to using query strings in mysql and I have tried to write this procedure to drop tables under certain conditions. I don't reall know what I'm doing wrong and need help with getting the procedure to work or for someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE String scheduler = 'select status from mysql.scheduler where id=0' ;
    DECLARE String auftragpos = 'SELECT count("SchemaName") FROM "SYS.Tables" where "SchemaName" = dwh and "Name" = lexware_fk_auftragpos';
    DECLARE String auftrag = 'SELECT count("SchemaName") FROM "SYS.Tables" where "SchemaName" = dwh and "Name" = lexware_fk_auftrag';
    
    IF(auftragpos > 1)
    BEGIN
        drop table "dwh.lexware_fk_auftragpos";
    END
    
    IF(auftrag > 1)
    BEGIN
        drop table "dwh.lexware_fk_auftrag";
    END   
    
END
```

Comment: You're not executing the queries. You're just assigning the query strings to the variables.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have `SYS.Tables`. That's in SQL-Server.

Comment: MySQL has `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for declaring a variable is

```
DECLARE variablename datatype;
```

So it should be

```
DECLARE auftragpos INT;
```

Then you need to assign the result of the query to the variable. You do that by putting the `SELECT` query in parentheses.

You also should not quote table names, and you need to quote the literal strings you're using for the schema and table names you're searching for.

```
SET auftragpos = (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dwh' AND TABLE_NAME = 'lexware_fk_auftragpos');
```

But there's really no need to do this. If you want to prevent an error from `DROP TABLE`, just add the `IF EXISTS` option.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dwh.lexware_fk_auftragpos;
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have used if exists for this procedure.